# Error starting out with pig

Tags: apache-pig

I just started with pig and a simple line of code that is supposed to read in data from a file called mary-

```
input = load 'mary' as (line);
```

is not working for me. 
I have this file in the folder from where I ran pig and this is the error I get -

```
Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 0>  mismatched input 'input' expecting EOF
```

This piece of code was taken from the first example of the book Programming_Pig.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the name `input` for a relation does not work as it is a [reserved keyword](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#reserved-keywords) in pig. Use another name for the relation such as

```
A = load 'mary' as (line);
```

and it will work.

My guess is that the version that was used for "Programming Pig" did not yet have this reserved keyword or it is simply wrong.